# Ok to ask a more specific version of a previous question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

At the end of May I asked [this question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/30289/different-google-searches-return-different-titles-for-the-same-page) about google searches returning different titles for the same page for different queries.

I used a hypothetical example for the sake of anonymity, and there were couple of good answers but they didn't help unfortunately.

So my question: Is it ok to ask a specific, non-abstracted version of the same question with all of the details and specifics spelled out?

Answer (score 3):

I'd recommend editing your existing question with the specifics over creating a question which might qualify as a duplicate, however, the nature of the original question (particularly as it appears to deal with how Google is retrieving proprietary information from its indexes) is going to make it difficult to answer with factual information.

Comment: Thanks @danlefree, I intended to outline all of the steps I've taken in the interim (quite a few) to see if there's any ommisions in what I've tried rather than a simple rephrase of the body of the question. So the title of the question would be similar, but the body much more detailed and specific. Does that make it the same question?

Comment: If the present answers would still apply to your revised question (even if they detail steps you've subsequently taken) then I would consider it the same question.

Comment: Thanks @danlefree, luckily I've finally found the solution. I'll update the question with that!